# Avoid duplicate stored procedure logic

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am trying to write a stored procedure with a `WHERE` clause that changes depending on which parameter is passed.

If `@categoryId` is passed, I want this procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.spCourses_GetCoursesByCategory
    @categoryId int, 
    @courseId varchar
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT CoursesUsersReviews.*, CoursesUsersJoin.*
    FROM
        (SELECT 
             Courses.Id, 
             COUNT(Reviews.Text) AS ReviewsCount, 
             COUNT(UserCourses.CourseId) AS EnrollmentCount
         FROM 
             Courses
         INNER JOIN 
             Reviews ON (Courses.Id = Reviews.CourseId)
         INNER JOIN 
             UserCourses ON (Courses.Id = UserCourses.CourseId)
         GROUP BY Courses.Id) CoursesUsersReviews
    INNER JOIN
        (SELECT 
             Courses.Id AS Id, Courses.Name AS CourseName, 
             Courses.Image AS CourseImage, Courses.Url AS CourseURL,
             Courses.Price AS CoursePrice, Courses.Featured AS Featured, 
             Courses.Rating AS Rating, 
             AspNetUsers.Name AS AuthorName, AspNetUsers.Avatar AS AuthorImage, 
             AspNetUsers.About AS AuthorProfile, AspNetUsers.Url AS AuthorURL
         FROM 
             dbo.Courses
         INNER JOIN 
             dbo.AspNetUsers ON (Courses.OwnerId = AspNetUsers.Id)
         WHERE 
             Courses.CategoryId = @categoryId) CoursesUsersJoin ON (CoursesUsersReviews.Id = CoursesUsersJoin.Id)
END
GO
```

If `@courseName` is passed, then I want this `WHERE` clause in my procedure:

```
WHERE Courses.Name = @courseName
```

How to do that without rewriting the entire procedure?

Comment: `@courseId varchar` --> oof, try passing a value with more than one character (always indicate the max length, e.g. `varchar(128)`).

Comment: @RhythmWasaLurker What problem does it cause?

Comment: @AmirLatif you have an answer below.

Comment: This is a set of requirements that gets really really hard to do well in a stored procedure setup - but it would be very easy when using an ORM like Entity Framework. Just saying ...

Comment: @marc_s I read that using stored procedures is better in complex queries for performance
also, to avoid redeploying the app by changing the query each time

Comment: I would very much doubt any significant performance benefit - but yes, you can redeploy the stored procedure without the app - if you really want that. But that benefit - as you can see now - comes at a cost - less flexibility. Which is more important to you? It's up to you to decide which approach gives you less trouble and more features and benefits ....

Comment: [This fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/w-OFcLCI) demonstrates the problem, @Amir.

Comment: ORMs aren't always a magical solution to variable parameters, either. ORMs can help with some of that complexity, but some ORMs are definitely more worthwhile than others - they can cause more problems than they solve, and they can generate SQL in a way that is difficult or impossible to tune. When optional parameters get overwhelming, dynamic SQL and option (recompile) are your friends (and conditional SQL you build in a stored procedure isn't really all that different from conditional SQL you build in C#).

Comment: Unclear why you are querying `Courses` twice anyway, you could remove one reference. And to top it off, your query is unlikely to be correct because `COUNT(someValue)` does not count distinct values, it only counts non-nulls. There is `COUNT(DISTINCT`, but you would be better off just keeping the aggreagtions separate. Eg https://dbfiddle.uk/eR1uu7UR

Comment: As far as your question: see the links above. Dynamic SQL is most performant, but can be difficult to write correctly and debug (be careful of injection). Alternatively just slap on `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` at the end of the query.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the naive way is:

```
WHERE 
  (@categoryId IS NULL OR Courses.CategoryId = @categoryId)
  AND
  (@courseName IS NULL OR Courses.Name = @courseName)
```

Naive because, at scale, it doesn't perform well (since you will get a single execution plan that favors a very specific value of just one of the parameters).